# How to use Kal calendar Api to draw calendar?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

How to use Kal calendar Api to draw calendar like this ?[image]

If any one know how to do this please give a quick reply with code

or any info on this topic

source code of this API is here http://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Answer (score 0):

Check http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary. There is a daily view developed inside. However, only monthly view showed in the example. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: I just followed the month calendar example and created a calendar example with tapkulibrary. It looks like what yours.